# GObject not a statement error

Tags: java

In my code I assign to a GObject variable a GObject that I get from another method.

```
private void myMethod() {
    if (sharp < 0) {
        nextMethod();
    } else
    GObject elem = getElem();
}

private GObject getElem(){
    GObject elem;
    elem = getElementAt(xCoord, yCoord);
    return elem;
}
```

The compiler is telling me that `GObject elem = getElem();` is not a statement. It looks like a statement to me. I am likely making just another rookie mistake.

Any ideas?

Comment: how is the method getElem() declared?

Comment: Post the full class. I can't tell what's the problem from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use an else with single line and without brackets, then it must be like:

```
else
    GObject elem = getElem();
```

Otherwise, just use brackets

```
else
{
    GObject elem = getElem();
}
```

**EDIT:**
When you did the following:

```
else
GObject elem = getElem();
```

The line below the `else` is just a new statement that is not inside the else. So the compiler is looking for something inside your `else`, but there isn't anything. You haven't indented your code in a way that puts the second statement inside the else.

Comment: That's exactly the same, the second is better for readability.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes it is the same. The second is much better for readability, and less error-prone. I just wanted to point out he can do it in both ways.

Comment: Indeed, but that **doesn't** answer OP question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think it's what's causing the problem. Unless he formatted the code in the question incorrectly.

Comment: Why do you think so? The two statements are exactly the same.

Comment: I think so because he's writing an else, but not enclosing anything with it. Unless you can have an else that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I do not understand why but enclosing it in brackets worked, @AliAlamiri Thank you. Perhaps you could explain why it doesn't work without those brackets? Isn't it essentially one line of code, so brackets are unnecessary?

Comment: @user2946352 It's because you have an else but haven't enclosed anything with it. It's an issue of indentation. That's why you always should use brackets to avoid such errors that may not be easy to spot. You can accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: @user2946352 and yes brackets are not necessary in this case, provided that you have indented the line correctly inside the else, which you haven't actually done :)

Comment: I thought indentation was only so other people would have an easier time reading your code. I did not know it was necessary for the actual compiling process. Lesson learned.

Comment: @AliAlamiri That's weird. Java has nothing to do with indentation as far as I know.